# How to use async await using functions

Tags: javascript, node.js

I made an api using express on Nodejs.
But I'm not sure whether I used async await well for it.

```
module.search = async(req, res) => {
    async function searchJibun(arg) {
        const resultJibun = await axios.get(
          'https://apis.com/code',
          {
            headers: {
              'KEY-ID': process.env.N_KEY_ID,
              'KEY': process.env.N_KEY
            },
            params: {
              query: arg
            }
          }
        );

        return resultJibun;
      }

      const { query } = req.body;
      const searchResult = [];
      let result = '';

      try {
        result = await searchJibun(query);
      } catch (error) {
        return res.status(200).json({
          success: false,
          code: 500,
          msg: 'Internal Server Error(1)',
          err: error
        });
      }
}
```

In this line, if I type 'await', does it work well?
Or the result is same due to my wrong used about async await totally?

```
result = await searchJibun(query);

result = searchJibun(query);
```

thank you so much for reading.

Comment: Note that it's not a good idea to mix status codes together. For instance, you've specified that the HTTP status code of a page be `200` when you've instead returned code `500`. Instead, just pass `500` to `res.status` and remove the `code` property from the resulting payload.

Comment: You are using it correctly

Comment: Edric Thank you so much for your coaching. But when I use this api in web-framework, the 500 status goes to .error() instead of .then(). I mean, even if the status is 500, I want to handle the result in .then() at front-side. How can I handle this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is definitely a difference between:

```
result = await searchJibun(query);

result = searchJibun(query);
```

To make things simple, think of `await` as a special function to unpacking value from Promise, and `async` for packing value into Promise.

Before I talk about how those two statements are different, you need to understand how `async` pack value.

To make things clearer I'm going to explain this concept using TypeScript.

---

### Async

Suppose you have a function that doubles a number.

```
function double_v1(x: number) { 
    return x * 2; 
}
```

The return type of the function above will be `number`. Because of that, the following expression is valid from the perspective of the type system.

```
double_v1(2) + 3
```

However, if you put `async` in front of the function, the return type changes to `Promise<number>`, even though you did not mention the word `Promise` anywhere in the code.

```
async function double_v2(x: number) {
    return x * 2;
}
```

Essentially, the code above is equivalent with the code below:

```
function double_v2(x: number) {
    return Promise.resolve(x * 2);
}
```

And the following expression will be invalid, because you cannot add numbers with Promise.

```
double_v2(2) + 3 // type error
```

---

### Await

As mentioned previously, `await` is for unpacking value from Promise. It means that if an expression has type of `Promise<T>`, then `await` will unpack the expression into type of `T`.

For example, the `double_v2` function has return type of `Promise<number>`, thus the `result` will have the type of `number`.

```
const result = await double_v2(3)
```

If you remove `await` from the statement, the type of `result` will become `Promise<number>` instead.

However, note that the other way round is not true. If you `await` for a non-Promise expression, you will get back the same type, it means that the two statements below are equivalent because the return type of `double_v1` is not Promise but number.

```
// Equivalent
result = await double_v1(3)
result = double_v1(3)
```

---

### Conclusion

The `searchJibun` function is mark with `async` keyword, it means it must return Promise, so using `await` on invocation of `searchJibun` will unpack the Promise, thus the following statement is not equivalent.

```
result = await searchJibun(query);  // type of result will be T

result = searchJibun(query);        // type of result will be Promise<T>
```

---

### Extra notes

`async` and `await` is actually based on the concept of *lifting* (a.k.a *packing*). In this case, `async` is *lift*, and `await` is *unlift*.

In the case of arrays, the square brackets is *lift* and the indexing operator is *unlift*.

For example, the type of `2` is `number`, but when you surround it with square brackets like this `[2]` you *lift* the type to become `Array<number>`.

To *unlift* an array, you use the indexing operator like this `[2][0]`, and this expression will the type of `number`.

In the case of `Promise`, `.resolve` is *lift* and `.then` is *unlift*. For example, you can lift the type of an expression `e` with type `T` to `Promise<T>` by writing `Promise.resolve(e)`, and then you can unlift it with `myPromise.then(e => {...})`

In the end, to really understand `async` and `await`, you just have to realise that they are just syntactic sugar for *lifting* and *unlifting* Promises.

In a sugarless world, the operations above could have been written in a more uniform style as such.

```
// Arrays
myArray = liftAsArray(1, 2, 3)
firstValue = unliftArray(myArray, 0)

// Promises
myPromise = liftAsPromise(1)
value = unliftPromise(myPromise)
```

Although this style of writing code is consistent, it is more verbose and thus harder to be read fast.

P/S: `async/await` are not purely syntactic sugar, they exists for compiler to perform some magic on your code, that's why there are performance differences between using `async/await` and `Promises`

Answer (score 1):

as long as your `searchJibun()` function is defined with  `async` you will need to wait for the response with the `await`

And within your async functions you will have to use the `await` to receive your api responses

I recommend you read this [article](https://javascript.info/async-await) to better understand